# On saving, Prettier formats "use strict"; to ('use strict'); & strict mode is not initialised?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm pretty new to coding & using `VS Code / Prettier`
I'm trying to turn on strict mode in my JS code, using `"use strict";`

when I save my file, Prettier formats the code from `"use strict"` to `('use strict')`;

which then as far as I can see means strict mode isn't initialised.
I couldn't find anyone else talking about this problem online anywhere, so wonder if anyone could shed any light on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have tried with a recent version of Prettier, this indicates you have put `"use strict";` at a wrong place.

`"use strict";` must appear before any code in the script, or when it is used within a function, it must appear before any code in the body of that function.

If you put `"use strict";` anywhere else, Prettier will add the parentheses.

You can reproduce this behaviour on the [Prettier playground](https://prettier.io/playground/).

> which then as far as I can see means strict mode isn't initialised

True. It must be a plain string literal, and `("use strict")` violates that rule.

Comment: I found that I had to include the semi-colon after the string too. Even if 'use strict' was on the first line of the file. Adding the semi-colon fixed the issue for me.